# How can I fix the VS2008 tool window buttons on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-10

I have to maintain a legacy codebase which for a variety of reasons, can only be worked on in Visual Studio 2008.

I noticed the Tool Windows' buttons for Menu, Pin, and Close have their icons replaced with the letters "H D A" or "H B A".

[image]

Whereas on Windows Server 2008 R2 (Windows 8.1) it looks like this:

[image]

My guess is that the font it uses for the buttons is either missing or being overridden. Does anyone know what font it is (so I can see if it's missing) or some other fix?

Comment: run such old VS version in a VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running Windows 10 for a few weeks I noticed the Visual Studio 2008 tool window caption buttons have been restored to their correct appearance without me having to do anything specifically, weird. No bug then, I guess :)